# android:windowLightStatusBar TRUE not working

Tags: android, statusbar, android-theme, android-styles, android-statusbar

I have the following style for my app:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

It works fine on most of the phones that I work with. (LG G5, Nexus 5, Moto G)
But I get this when I run it on a LeEco Pro 2:
https://s3.amazonaws.com/uploads.hipchat.com/39260/829560/ae6hlIUj0Wu7pJx/upload.png

As you can see. The BAR is completely black, and you can't see the text. Does anyone else encountered this issue? Is it possible to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added this to the style and it worked:

```
      <item name="android:statusBarColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#ffffff</item>
```